# (Array/ML Vector/MLlib Vector) RDD to ML Vector Dataframe coulmn

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I need to convert an RDD to a single column o.a.s.ml.linalg.Vector DataFrame, in order to use the ML algorithms, specifically K-Means for this case. This is my RDD:

```scala
val parsedData = sc.textFile("/digits480x.csv").map(s => Row(org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors.dense(s.split(',').slice(0,64).map(_.toDouble))))
```

I tried doing what [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32745119/how-do-i-convert-an-rdd-with-a-sparsevector-column-to-a-dataframe-with-a-column) answer suggests with no luck, I suppose because you end up with a MLlib Vector, it throws a mismatch error when running the algorithm. Now if I change this:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vectors, VectorUDT}

val schema = new StructType()
  .add("features", new VectorUDT())
```

to this:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.{Vectors, VectorUDT}

val parsedData = sc.textFile("/digits480x.csv").map(s => Row(org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors.dense(s.split(',').slice(0,64).map(_.toDouble))))

val schema = new StructType()
  .add("features", new VectorUDT())
```

I would get an error because ML VectorUDT is private.

I also tried converting the RDD as an array of doubles to Dataframe, and get the ML Dense Vector like this:

```scala
var parsedData = sc.textFile("/home/pililo/Documents/Mi_Memoria/Codigo/Datasets/Digits/digits480x.csv").map(s => Row(s.split(',').slice(0,64).map(_.toDouble)))

parsedData: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]

val schema2 = new StructType().add("features", ArrayType(DoubleType))

schema2: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(features,ArrayType(DoubleType,true),true))

val df = spark.createDataFrame(parsedData, schema2)

df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [features: array<double>]

val df2 = df.map{ case Row(features: Array[Double]) => Row(org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors.dense(features)) }
```

Which throws the following error, even though `spark.implicits._` is imported:

```
error: Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the top of my head:

1. Use `csv` source and `VectorAssembler`:

   ```
   import scala.util.Try
   import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg._
   import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler

   val path: String = ???

   val n: Int = ???
   val m:Int = ???

   val raw = spark.read.csv(path)
   val featureCols = raw.columns.slice(n, m)

   val exprs = featureCols.map(c => col(c).cast("double"))
   val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
     .setInputCols(featureCols)
     .setOutputCol("features")

   assembler.transform(raw.select(exprs: _*)).select($"features")
   ```
2. Use `text` source and UDF:

   ```
   def parse_(n: Int, m: Int)(s: String) = Try(
     Vectors.dense(s.split(',').slice(n, m).map(_.toDouble))
   ).toOption

   def parse(n: Int, m: Int) = udf(parse_(n, m) _)

   val raw = spark.read.text(path)

   raw.select(parse(n, m)(col(raw.columns.head)).alias("features"))
   ```
3. Use `text` source and drop wrapping `Row`

   ```
   spark.read.text(path).as[String].map(parse_(n, m)).toDF
   ```

Comment: Wow thanks for the answer, I'll give them a try. Any idea if 1) would be most efficient? I actually wanted to do something like that but was missing the way to slice the columns for input cols, since they're 64. Also I'd really appreciate it if you could explain this part in 1) if you can: exprs: _*. Is it like select all cols? Thanks a lot!

Comment: 2 and 3 can be slightly faster because there is no csv parsing involved but I wouldn't focus on that. 1. can be improved by providing schema to reader. Finally `_*` is all about [varargs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1008783/1560062). It takes a sequence and "unpacks" it as arguments for select.