# How to create a DataFrame from RDD of SparseVectors in Java

Tags: java, dataframe, rdd

I was trying to convert an `RDD` of `SparseVector` into a `DataFrame`. I have done this in `Scala` and `Python` but never in `Java`, indeed the answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32745119/how-do-i-convert-an-rdd-with-a-sparsevector-column-to-a-dataframe-with-a-column).

I tried to find examples that covered this topic but I couldn't find any. Nevertheless, it apparently works the same way as Scala, but I couldn't replicate it.

Answer (score 0):

I could finally achieve it. A proper schema that will be used to convert a `SparseVector` must set as `dataType` a `new VectorUDT`, notice that if you follow the examples they normally use *DataTypes*.*something*, so it was pretty tough.

```
List<StructField> fields = new ArrayList<>();
StructField field = DataTypes.createStructField("features", new VectorUDT(), true);

fields.add(field);

StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(fields);
```